# Adding Excel workbook to ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-joins, excel

I have added excel files to ArcMap numerous times without any problem and then joined them to shapefiles, but, for some reason, today I am getting an error I have never seen before.

The error reads:

> Could not add the specified data object to the map. AN underlying
>   error occurred. Class not registered.

Has anyone else ever had this issue and managed to resolve it?

Comment: I have just tried in QGIS as well and it works fine here, but not in ArcMap

Comment: What versions of ArcMap and Excel?  When asking a question, always remember to include the version of the software you are using.

Answer (score 2):

I have manage to resolve this by downloading the following and then joining using the Data Management in the Toolbox

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734

> This download will install a set of components that can be used to
>   facilitate transfer of data between 2007 Microsoft Office System files
>   and non-Microsoft Office applications.